# C# public interface and signature variables

Tags: c#, winforms, interface

I am trying to do a total rewrite of my first C# Windows Forms app.  Better ways of doing things.

Part of that process is I want to start using interfaces. I chose a class that will only have one signature variable with one method to base the interface on. The signature variable of the interface has a value assigned in a form and then the class is called.

This public variable has no value when the class executes. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Thankful for any help you can provide.

Interface definition:

```
public interface IAbsolutePath
{
    string strPath { get; set; }

    bool CheckForDriveSelected();
}
```

Calling the interface

```
public partial class frm_Copydata : Form
{
    public string strPath{get; set;}

    public frm_Copydata()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn_SelectInput_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // bool bolInputSelected = true;
        if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            txb_InputFolderPath.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
            strPath = txb_InputFolderPath.Text;

            IAbsolutePath WasDriveSelected = new cl_CheckForDriveSelected();

            bool bolDriveLetter = WasDriveSelected.CheckForDriveSelected();
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the class and method:

```
class cl_CheckForDriveSelected : IAbsolutePath
{
    public string strPath { get; set; }

    public bool CheckForDriveSelected()
    {
        DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

        for (int i = 0; i < drives.Count(); i++)
        {
            var strtest = drives[i].Name;

            if (strPath == drives[i].Name)
            {
                var strMsgBoxTitle = "Select a folder for input";
                var strMsgBoxMsg = "You must choose a folder and not a drive letter." +
                       "\n" +
                        "Please make another selection";

                MessageBoxButtons btnButtons = MessageBoxButtons.OK;
                MessageBox.Show(strMsgBoxMsg, strMsgBoxTitle, btnButtons, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

I was hoping to get my feet wet with something simple before I applied interfaces to other areas of the app that could use this type of logic.

Comment: Can you make your question clearer.  What is the issue?  Are you getting an error? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The path is set in the `frm_Copydata` instead of `cl_CheckForDriveSelected`, hence `cl_CheckForDriveSelected.strPath` is null. Also, you might want to follow [C# Naming Conventions](https://github.com/ktaranov/naming-convention/blob/master/C%23%20Coding%20Standards%20and%20Naming%20Conventions.md). Have fun!

Comment: You should describe what a *signature variable* is, in your view. It looks like you think that, since two classes have a Property with the same name, a value assigned in one class is automagically transferred to the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not assigning value to public property of `IAbsolutePath` implemented class. You need to assign value in following way :

```
 IAbsolutePath WasDriveSelected = new cl_CheckForDriveSelected()
  {
        strPath =  txb_InputFolderPath.Text
  }
```

You don't need `strPath` field in frm_Copydata.

Comment: You probably want to pass the value in the constructor